# No intellisense without the html & body tag in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

If I create a .aspx-page in Visual Studio and delete the html & body tags, then the .NET intellisense will stop working.
Why is the html & body tags required to make the .NET intellisense work?

I have to remove the html & body tags because it is a RSS-feed I am creating and not a regular web page.

Just to clarify, it is the intellisense in the html source view that is not working.
The intellisense in the code-behind view is working like it should.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

M

Comment: I don't think you should use a `Page` to create an rss feed. Instead I would recommend using [this rss library](http://www.rssdotnet.com/documents/code_examples.html) and using an [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3ff8w4a(VS.71).aspx) to serve it.

Comment: Or you could take a look at the System.ServiceModel.Syndication classes in .NET 3.5 if you're using that platform: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this question?